# error: assignment of read-only location ‘arr2.IntArray::operator[](1)’ arr2[1] = 24;

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I'm a beginner in c++ who is learning to use overloaded operations. In my main program I have this code:

```
IntArray arr2(3)
arr2[1] = 24;
```

In my header, I have this code

```
class IntArray {
  char *elt;
  int size
public:
  const int& operator[] (int i);
```

In my .cpp, I have this constructor:

```
/* one-integer constructor */
IntArray::IntArray(int sz) {
  elt = new char[sz];
  for (int i = 0; i<sz; i++)
    elt[i] = 0;
  size = sz;
}
```

and this index operator

```
/* Index operator */
const int& IntArray::operator[] (int i) {
   if (i < 0) {
     cout << "warning: value out of bounds" <<endl;
   return elt[0];
   }
   else if (i > size) {
     cout << "warning: value out of bounds" <<endl;
   return elt[size];
   }
   else
    return elt[i];
   }
```

I get this error when I try to assign the value 24 to an indexed position in the array

> error: assignment of read-only location ‘arr2.IntArray::operator’
>   arr2[1] = 24;

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a reference to const - that means it's not modifiable (it's a "read-only location" per the error message). But then you're trying to modify it anyway.

What you meant to do was return a reference to non-const:

```
int& operator[] (int i) {
    // same as before
}
```

For this to work, `elt` needs to be fixed to have the correct type: `int*`. After all, you're making an array of `int`s not an array of `char`s.

---

Note: printing an error for out of bounds isn't very helpful. You should prefer to either throw an exception or simply assert that the given index is in bounds.

Comment: sure, but then I get this error: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
     return elt[0];

Comment: Thanks!! I changed the type to *int in the constructor and it solved it.